# Interpreting 17th century German dates?

Tags: germany, 17th-century, date

I am working on the biography of a distant relative, Anna Bertschinger. The hand-written notes I got handed down from my grandfather state:

> verm. 2. post trin. 1649

I understand that this refers to a wedding date, presumably corresponding to the second Sunday after Trinity, which would make it the Sunday ten weeks after Easter. (or is "2. post trin." the second /day/ after Trinity Sunday?) According to http://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/easter-date-tables.html?century=17, Easter Sunday 1649 was April 4th, so that would make "2. post trin." the 13th of June, 1649.

Is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

original, probably an exact transcript of the church register entry

> "verm. 2. post trin. 1649"

with abbreviations expanded, German and Latin

> "vermahlt 2. [Sonntag] post Trinitatis 1649"

English

> "married on the 2nd Sunday after Trinity Sunday 1649"

[Moveable Feast Day Calendar for: Germany](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Moveable_Feast_Day_Calendar_for:_Germany) states that although Catholic states had converted earlier (and provides a list of regions and dates), most Protestant areas of Germany did not convert to the Gregorian calendar until 1700. Be careful that you use the correct Easter charts for your record's location. (See [Gregorian calendar - Adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption) for other countries).

For example, according to [Ecclesiastical dates](http://people.albion.edu/imacinnes/calendar/Ecclesiastical_dates.html) and the Familysearch Wiki's Denmark: Moveable Feast Days (which also applies to Protestant Germany), in 1649, Easter was on March 25, and Trinity Sunday was May 20, 
so the above wedding may have been on June 3 [Julian calendar], depending on the location.

The dates noted in the question (Easter on Apr 4 and wedding on Jun 13) are according to Gregorian calendar.

Unfortunately, my old favorite, [Marcos J. Montes' Ecclesiastical Calendar](http://www.smart.net/~mmontes/ec-cal.html), which was widely recognized and had multiple date sets, is no longer available.